# Unity 2D knockback, change transform.position to AddForce?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am trying to make it so that in my EnemyAI script when they get hit with a bullet, they get knockback. This code I have worked but it teleports them backward, I want to use AddForce instead but I am not sure how I would change it here. can anyone help? My enemy already has a Rigidbody2D named rb in this code. Thanks in advance!

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            Vector2 difference = transform.position - other.transform.position;
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + difference.x, transform.position.y + difference.y);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public float knockbackForce;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        Vector2 difference = (transform.position - other.transform.position).normalized;
        Vector2 force = difference * knockbackForce;
        rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse); //if you don't want to take into consideration enemy's mass then use ForceMode.VelocityChange
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Panda Strong code is perfect, just in case of 2d you need to use ForceMode2D.Impulse instead of ForceMode.Impulse!

Comment: If You have improvement to the answer of Panda Strong, please write it as a comment. If. You would write it almost the same but see that something should be changed like your words state, make a full code example to not look like just a comment and rightfully get the points :)